# Stop queue listening RabbitMQ using java

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue

Hi I am using rabbitMQ in my java application. When I stop the application I need to make sure stop the queue listener (stop receiving messages from the queue) before stop the application. 
I am not sure whether I need to call **channel.close()**  or **channel.basicCancel("tag")**.
Following code was written to stop the queue listening.

```
if(myContext.myChannel.isOpen()){ 

  //myChannel is the one I am using to listen to queue 
  myContext.myChannel.basicCancel("OP"); 

  //myContext.myChannel.close(); 
}else{ 
   return ok("Channel is not open"); 
}
```

Comment: Show some code if you want help. Read the manual.

Comment: on stopping my application I am calling below code

`if(myContext.myChannel.isOpen()){      
    //myChannel is the one I am using to listen to queue
 myContext.myChannel.basicCancel("OP");
 //myContext.myChannel.close();
}else{
   return ok("Channel is not open");
}`

Comment: Hi Manoj,
Same problem im also facing, can you please help me to get the "myContext" Object.If you share the code that would be great help for me. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want stop listener you have to:

```
 Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
 Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
 channel.queueDeclare("myQueue", false, false, false, null);
 MyConsumer consumer = new MyConsumer(channel);
 String consumerTag = channel.basicConsume("myQueue", false, consumer);
 System.out.println("press any key to terminate");
 System.in.read();

 channel.basicCancel(consumerTag);<----- this stop listening
 channel.close(); <--- this close the channel and eventually all listening
 connection.close();<-- this close the connection and all channels
```

Please read this about `"isOpen"` method: https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html

> Use of the isOpen() method of channel and connection objects is not
>   recommended for  production code, because the value returned by the
>   method is dependent on the existence of the shutdown cause.

Comment: Thank you. basicCancel("tag") worked with my case. I managed to stop the queue listening before stop the application.

Comment: @manojprasanna , but how to get consumerTag and same channel in different part of code , on which it was listening ?

Answer (score 0):

If your are using AMQP/Rabbit, you can try one of these:

```
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

    //
    //autoStartup = false, prevents handling messages immedeatly. You need to start each listener itselve. 
    //
    factory.setAutoStartup(false); 

    factory.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
    return factory;
}
```

or in app.yml/props:

```
rabbitmq.listener.auto-startup: false
rabbitmq.listener.simple.auto-startup: false
```

or: 
give your @RabbitListener a id

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "myQ", id = "myQ")
...
```

and :

```
@Autowired
private RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry;

MessageListenerContainer listener = 
   rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("myQ");
    ...
listener.start();
...
listener.stop();
```